# Why is my Phone Dialer procedure not being called on Android in Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi

I made a program based on the example of this tutorial:

[Mobile Tutorial: Using the Phone Dialer on Mobile Devices (iOS and Android)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_the_Phone_Dialer_on_Mobile_Devices_(iOS_and_Android))

The `CallStateChanged` procedure is not called. How can I make it be called and display the state of the call?

I tested the app on Android 10 and 12. All permissios have been issued.

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, System.Permissions,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Media, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Objects, System.Actions, FMX.ActnList, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
  FMX.Effects, FMX.Filter.Effects,
  FMX.PhoneDialer,
  FMX.Platform, FMX.Edit, FMX.ListBox, FMX.Layouts,System.IOUTils, androidapi.Jni.Telephony;

const
  AUDIO_FILENAME = 'test.mp3';
type
  TAudioRecPlayForm = class(TForm)
    btnStartRec: TButton;
    btnStopRec: TButton;
    btnStartPlay: TButton;
    btnStopPlay: TButton;
    ToolBar1: TToolBar;
    Label1: TLabel;
    ToolBar2: TToolBar;
    MediaPlayer: TMediaPlayer;
    ActionList: TActionList;
    actStartRecording: TAction;
    actStopRecording: TAction;
    actPlay: TAction;
    actStop: TAction;
    edtTelephoneNumber: TEdit;
    btnMakeCall: TButton;
    lblCallState: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure btnMakeCallClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure actStartRecordingExecute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure actStopRecordingExecute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure actStopExecute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure actPlayExecute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ActionListUpdate(Action: TBasicAction; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure SetArsOnCallStateChanged(const ACallID: String; const ACallState: TCallState);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FMicrophone: TAudioCaptureDevice;
    PhoneDialerService: IFMXPhoneDialerService;
    FCallPhonePermission: string;
    FRecordCallPermission: string;
    FStatePhonePermission: string;
    procedure DisplayRationale(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
    procedure MakePhoneCallPermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
    function HasMicrophone: Boolean;
    function IsMicrophoneRecording: Boolean;
    procedure RequestPermissionsResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    Mic: TAudioCaptureDevice;

  end;

var
  AudioRecPlayForm: TAudioRecPlayForm;
  Dial: TPhoneDialerService;
implementation
uses
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os,
  FMX.DialogService;

{$R *.fmx}

function GetAudioFileName(const AFileName: string): string;
begin
  Result := TPath.GetTempPath + '/' + AFileName;
end;

procedure TAudioRecPlayForm.ActionListUpdate(Action: TBasicAction; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  actStartRecording.Enabled := not IsMicrophoneRecording and HasMicrophone;
  actStopRecording.Enabled := IsMicrophoneRecording;
  actStop.Enabled := Assigned(MediaPlayer.Media) and (MediaPlayer.State = TMediaState.Playing);
  actPlay.Enabled := FileExists(GetAudioFileName(AUDIO_FILENAME)) and (MediaPlayer.State <> TMediaState.Playing);
end;

procedure TAudioRecPlayForm.actPlayExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if IsMicrophoneRecording then
    actStopRecording.Execute;

  MediaPlayer.FileName := GetAudioFileName(AUDIO_FILENAME);
  MediaPlayer.Play;
end;

procedure TAudioRecPlayForm.actStartRecordingExecute(Sender: TObject);
const
  PermissionRecordAudio = 'android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO';

begin
  actStop.Execute;

  { get the microphone device }
  FMicrophone := TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.DefaultAudioCaptureDevice;

  if HasMicrophone then
  begin
    { and attempt to record to 'test.wav' file }
    FMicrophone.FileName := GetAudioFileName(AUDIO_FILENAME);
    PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([PermissionRecordAudio], RequestPermissionsResult, DisplayRationale);
  end
  else
    TDialogService.ShowMessage('No microphone is available.');
end;

procedure TAudioRecPlayForm.DisplayRationale(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
begin
  TDialogService.ShowMessage('Нам нужно получить разрешение на запись звука с помощью вашего микрофона',
    procedure(const AResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      APostRationaleProc;
    end)
end;

procedure TAudioRecPlayForm.RequestPermissionsResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
begin
  if (Length(AGrantResults) = 1) then
  begin
    case AGrantResults[0] of
      TPermissionStatus.Granted:
        try
          FMicrophone.StartCapture;
        except
          TDialogService.ShowMessage('Ваш девайс не поддерживается');
        end;
      TPermissionStatus.Denied: TDialogService.ShowMessage('Нельзя записывать звук без соответствующего разрешения!');
      TPermissionStatus.PermanentlyDenied: TDialogService.ShowMessage('Если вы решите, что хотите использовать функцию аудиозаписи в этом приложении, пожалуйста, зайдите в настройки приложения и включите разрешение микрофона!');
    end;
  end
  else
    TDialogService.ShowMessage('Что-то пошло не так с проверкой разрешений');
end;

procedure TAudioRecPlayForm.actStopExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MediaPlayer.Stop;
end;

procedure TAudioRecPlayForm.actStopRecordingExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { stop capturing audio from the microphone }
  if IsMicrophoneRecording then
    try
      FMicrophone.StopCapture;
    except
      TDialogService.ShowMessage('Предоставьте разрешение!');
    end;
end;

procedure TAudioRecPlayForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ImprPhoneState:string;
begin
  FMicrophone := TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.DefaultAudioCaptureDevice;
  FCallPhonePermission := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.CALL_PHONE);
  { test whether the PhoneDialer services are supported }
  TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXPhoneDialerService, PhoneDialerService);
  if Assigned(PhoneDialerService) then
    PhoneDialerService.OnCallStateChanged:=SetArsOnCallStateChanged else ShowMessage('Телефону пизда');
end;

function TAudioRecPlayForm.HasMicrophone: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Assigned(FMicrophone);
end;

function TAudioRecPlayForm.IsMicrophoneRecording: Boolean;
begin
  Result := HasMicrophone and (FMicrophone.State = TCaptureDeviceState.Capturing);
end;

procedure TAudioRecPlayForm.btnMakeCallClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if PhoneDialerService <> nil then
  begin
    if edtTelephoneNumber.Text <> '' then  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([FCallPhonePermission], MakePhoneCallPermissionRequestResult, DisplayRationale)
    else
    begin
      TDialogService.ShowMessage('Пожалуйста, наберите номер');
      edtTelephoneNumber.SetFocus;
    end;
  end
  else
    TDialogService.ShowMessage('Служба PhoneDialer не поддерживается');
end;

 procedure TAudioRecPlayForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 PhoneDialerService.OnCallStateChanged:= SetArsOnCallStateChanged ;
end;

procedure TAudioRecPlayForm.MakePhoneCallPermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
begin
  if (Length(AGrantResults) = 1) and (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
    PhoneDialerService.Call(edtTelephoneNumber.Text)
  else
    TDialogService.ShowMessage('Невозможно сделать телефонный звонок, потому что не было получено необходимое разрешение');
end;
procedure TAudioRecPlayForm.SetArsOnCallStateChanged(const ACallID: String; const ACallState: TCallState);
 Begin
  case ACallState of
        TCallState(0): ShowMessage('Call Connected');
        TCallState(1): ShowMessage('Call Connected');
        TCallState(2): ShowMessage('Call Incoming');
        TCallState(3): ShowMessage('Call Dialing');
        TCallState(4): ShowMessage('Call Disconnected');
     end;
 End;
end.
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As a minimum, please show your implementation.

Comment: A link to the official sample application is not useful. We need to see your own code, in the form of a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. Looking at what EMBT did is useless, as it doesn't show any mistakes or errors you may have introduced in your implementation. If you want to ask about their code, contact EMBT support.

Comment: Also, you'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: It would also help if you specified what version of Delphi you are using. Out of the box, using the PhoneDialer app on Delphi 10.4.x locks up on start on Android 12 due to [this issue](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-39445).